# change source of octomap

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to customize the octomap_server with this scenario that just points with yellow color considered as occupied and all others considered as free, so what is the best way to do it ? my mean is i should get the source code of octomap_server and modify it and compile and use it, or is there a easiest way?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105131/change-source-of-octomap/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See reply at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/octomap/0sL8Q4bVRyk

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0